# Registry location of DirectShow audio capture devices

Tags: winapi, audio, registry, directshow

I am executing VLC from my application to capture and encode from a DirectShow audio capture device.  VLC sends the encoded data to my application via STDOUT.  I need a way to enumerate  DirectShow audio capture devices.  Unfortunately, VLC doesn't seem to provide any non-GUI way for this.

While looking for a simple way to get a list of device names, I stumbled on these registry keys where child keys are named after audio capture devices:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ActiveMovie\devenum 64-bit\{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ActiveMovie\devenum\{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}`

Is this registry location guaranteed to be in the same place for other machines and recent versions of DirectX?  Short of implementing a ton of DirectX code, is there some other way to get a list of the DirectShow audio device names?  (Possibly through some output of a diagnostic tool.)

Comment: `1` The simple enumeration way is through API `2` a small correction - DirectShow is not DirectX `3` enumeration is more than registry entries: there are enumerators which supply device monikers programmatically, not just from registry key `4` a disgnostic tool is [here](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/EnumerateAudioCaptureFilterCapabilities/Win32/Release), look for "Friendly Name" lines (step up from there for C++ source code). You can also enumerate with Windows SDK `GraphEdt.exe` interactively.

Comment: @RomanR., Thank you for that helpful information!  Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: I was not sure if you're going to be happy with this knowledge, or you would still look for ways to tweak it on registry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of DirectShow (a Windows core API, not a part of DirectX anymore) devices is provided by enumerators listing specific category (audio input devices in this case, `CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory`) on request. This is the `GUID` in question and registry does not necessarily contains entries for all devices there. Instead, enumerator provides the list of devices programmatically via API, combining the available devices of different types.

There is no way to affect enumeration order in well defined/documented way.

The easiest way to enumerate the devices is Windows SDK GraphEdt.exe tool, or its nicer alternate options GraphStudio/[GraphStudioNext](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/). `Ctrl+F` and then select the category:

[image]

You can also enumerate devices and their capabilities with [EnumerateAudioCaptureFilterCapabilities](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/EnumerateAudioCaptureFilterCapabilities/Win32/Release) command line tool ([source code](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/EnumerateAudioCaptureFilterCapabilities)), where "Friendly Name" lines list devices in enumeration order:

```
Moniker Display Name: @device:cm:{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini
Friendly Name: Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini
  Pin: Capture
    Capability Count: 23
    Capability 0:
    AM_MEDIA_TYPE:
      .bFixedSizeSamples: 1
      .bTemporalCompression: 0
      .lSampleSize: 4
      .cbFormat: 18
    WAVEFORMATEX:
      .wFormatTag: 1
      .nChannels: 2
      .nSamplesPerSec: 44100
      .nAvgBytesPerSec: 176400
      .nBlockAlign: 4
      .wBitsPerSample: 16
      .cbSize: 0
```

To affect the order, such as to place a device on interest on top of the list, I can only think of API hooking, which is a possible thing but not recommended for wide use due to alteration of standard system behavior.