# How to set the virtual camera as the default webcam on Windows?

Tags: windows, webcam, directshow

I'm trying to implement a virtual camera using DirectShow on Windows. So far I have registered a virtual camera using regsvr32, and it appears in the camera input list of 32 bit applications such as Skype and Zoom.

[image]

The problem is, in the case of some applications I have to open the app's settings and select the virtual camera manually. I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically set the virtual camera as the default webcam source, in all applications. Is the webcam list sorted by a specific order? (say, camera device id or sth.) and is it possible for my virtual camera to be selected as the camera source in every application?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296438/868014, applies to video as well.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks, it gave me a clue to start